# Fundamental group of a knot

Tags: algebraic-topology

If the circle and any knot are homeomorphic as topological spaces, why do they have different fundamental groups?

Answer (score 6):

The knot group isn't the fundamental group of the knot, it's the fundamental group of the *complement* of the knot.

Comment: And to answer the question that wasn't asked, knotted and unknotted circles *do* have the same fundamental group.

Comment: The practice of referring to the "fundamental group of the knot" rather than the fundamental group of its complement is conventional sloppiness.

Comment: This seems a good place to note that, for such purposes, a knot $K$ should really be thought of in terms of a pair $(X,K)$, where $X$ is typically $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $S^3$.